# Display a user's profile name and image through the Facebook instance for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I've integrated the Facebook [sso](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#register) for iOS and have the single sign on implemented and working.  How would I go about displaying a user's profile name and image through the Facebook instance for iOS.

I'm unable to find a tutorial for this (that's recent) and am a little confused. any help would be great. thanks.

Comment: Facebook site tutorial is best for facebook-ios-sdk than any other tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Graph API and go through it in facebook site http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

Try this document in that link

[image]

Comment: thank you. after         [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:facebook];
could I then set that value to a string like: NSString *me = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:facebook]]; ?

Comment: No. check below that. There is a method request:didLoad: method to get a successful callback. You will get a data in that method.

Comment: so if I use: - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{
    
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:facebook];

} how would I then call that from another method? thanks for all your help by the way.

Comment: oh oh .. not like that. You just [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:facebook]; call this wherever you want. The result about the user will get in that method - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result { NSLog(@"%@",result); } like this.Try that.

Comment: any idea why I would be getting the warning Sending 'ProjectAppDelegate *' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FBRequestDelegate>' from         [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"platform/posts" andDelegate:self];

Comment: - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result { NSLog(@"%@",result); } is a FBRequestDelegate method. You have to include in your view controller like @interface viewController:UIViewController<FBRequestDelegate>{ } in the top.

Comment: I had <FBSessionDelegate, FBDialogDelegate> for protocols. thanks for that! I still don't see an output message in the console though for - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result { NSLog(@"%@",result); }

Comment: Try this..[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self]];

Comment: I have that in my applicationDidFinishLaunching method. I think what I'm missing is how to call the - (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {...} method from the applicationDidFinishLaunching method. I'm not sure how to do this. thanks again

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9473/discussion-between-r-a-and-hanumandev)